# Bootstrap layout with overflown row

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I tried looking in google but couldn't find anything proper and as stackoverflow is the most helpful community in the world, I guess I will try here.

I am working on a very specific shop layout and I am stuck at one point.

Here is the main mockup: http://ccommerce.c-call.eu/

and here is what should happen if someone select the category: http://ccommerce.c-call.eu/product-tab

The problem is with responsiveness of the second one. Category presentation row is:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
       [CATEGORY]
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
       [CATEGORY]
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
       [CATEGORY]
    </div>
</div>
```

and when you enable the category tab it goes like:

```
<div class="col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    [CATEGORIES col-xx-4]
</div>
<div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
   [CATEGORY TAB]
</div>
```

What I want is that in XS view the category presentation should be one row with overflow, like in table-responsive bootstrap class, basically, big view should be like:
[image: bigview]

and small view (xs, under 768px) should be like:
[image: smallview]

right now small view is:
[image: small-wrong]

is it possible to do it like that? i am not really into javascript, probably some js with lots of class swapping would help, but maybe there is simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change css properies via media query on categories container - add overflow-x: auto; white-space: nowrap; and on category items change display to inline-block.

Comment: nailed it. + change col-xs-4 of elements into xs-12, otherwise they appear really small. thanks.